# How to run Elisa music player

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, multimedia, flatpak, audio-player

I have followed the instructions under the article  [How to Install KDE’s Elisa Music Player in Ubuntu 18.04](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/10/install-elisa-music-player-ubuntu-18-04/), namely:

```
sudo apt-get install flatpak
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
flatpak install flathub org.kde.elisa
```

All went well. Running again last command I get

```
Skipping: org.kde.elisa/x86_64/stable is already installed
```

Running `elisa`  or `org.kde.elisa` gives `command not found`.

I cannot find it with the program launcher (nor with krunner; I'm in Kubuntu 18.04).

Searching in Discover, nothing found.

Searching "elisa" in Dolphin at `/`, all that is found is under `/var/lib/flatpak/app/org.kde.elisa/`.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installing Elisa, and prior to rebooting, the only way I had to running it was executing

```
flatpak run org.kde.elisa
```

After rebooting, typing Elisa in the application launcher started to work.